# No me crea la sesion en php con datos de una tabla MYSQL

Tags: php

tengo un problema que no soy capaz de ver. Quiero crear una sesion con los datos de una tabla, este es el codigo html:

```
 <main>
    <div id="login">
        <form action="php/comprobarLogin.php" method="POST" id="formLogin">
            <legend>Login: </legend>
            <label>Usuario: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" size="30" maxlength="100" id="nombre" />
            <label>Contraseña: </label><input type="text" name="contra" size="30" maxlength="100" id="contra" />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" id="enviar" />
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
```

Que me lleva al comprobarLogin.php

```
    <?php
/* Cargo los archivos .php que contienen la conexion a la bbdd y llama a las funciones para indicar la zona horaria y el inicio de sesion */
include "../seguridad/sesionesbd.php";
include "../seguridad/inicioSesion.php";

error_reporting(0);

if (!isset($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['nombre']) ){
    echo "NO LLEGA NOMBRE";
    //header("Location: ../login.html");
}

if (!isset($_POST['contra']) || empty($_POST['contra'])){
    echo "NO LLEGA contra";
    //header("Location: ../login.html");

}
$nombre=strip_tags(trim($_POST['nombre']));
$contra=strip_tags(trim($_POST['contra']));

/* Creacion del canal y conexion a la DB */
$canal=@mysqli_connect(IP,USUARIO,CLAVE,BD);

if (!$canal){
    echo "Ha ocurrido el error: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." ".mysqli_connect_error()."<br />";
    exit;
}

mysqli_set_charset($canal,"utf8");

/* Select para comprobar que el usuario y la contraseña sean correctos */
$comprobarUsuario="select usuario, contraseña, perfil, id_persona from claves where usuario=?";

$consulta=mysqli_prepare($canal,$comprobarUsuario);

if (!$consulta){
    echo "Ha ocurrido el error: ".mysqli_errno($canal)." ".mysqli_error($canal)."<br />";
    exit;   
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta,"s",$uusuario);

$uusuario=$nombre;

mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);

/* Nombre de las variables que van a contener la informacion que quiero */
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($consulta, $nnombre,$ccontraseña, $pperfil, $iid_persona);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($consulta);

$n=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($consulta);

/* Como solo hay 1 usuario posible, no puede ser diferente de 1 */
if ($n!=1){
    //header("Location: ../login.html");
    exit;
}

$perfil = $pperfil;

$id_persona = $iid_persona;

mysqli_stmt_fetch($consulta);

mysqli_stmt_close($consulta);

/* La contraseña esta encriptada, se desencripta y compara */
if (password_verify($contra, $ccontraseña)) {
    unset($consulta);
} else {
    echo "contraseña erronea";
    //header("Location: ../login.html");
}

/* Como el usuario existe, con el id_usuario voy a sacar los datos del usuario */
$datosUsuario="select id_persona, nombre, apellido, nif, telefono, direccion, zona from persona where id_persona=?";

$consulta=mysqli_prepare($canal,$datosUsuario);

if (!$consulta){
    echo "algo salio mal";
    //header("Location: ../login.html");
}

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta,"i",$id);

$id=$id_persona;

mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($consulta);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($consulta, $iid_persona, $nnombre,$aapellido, $nnif, $ttelefono, $ddireccion,$zzona,$pperfil);

mysqli_stmt_fetch($consulta);

mysqli_stmt_close($consulta);

mysqli_close($canal);

//Se inicia sesión que luego tendra los datos del usuario para trabajar con ellos
inicioSesion();
$_SESSION['id_persona'] = $iid_persona;
$_SESSION['usuario']    = $nnombre;
$_SESSION['apellido']   = $aapellido;
$_SESSION['nif']        = $nnif;
$_SESSION['telefono']   = $ttelefono;
$_SESSION['direccion']  = $ddireccion;
$_SESSION['zona']       = $zzona;
$_SESSION['perfil']     = $pperfil;

?>
```

Como no hay errores, me lleva al index, pero los datos no se guardan en la sesion, y no se porque, no consigo ver el error. La sesion se crea, porque veo en los echo (que no he puesto) X nombre y X perfil pero los demas datos no... es lo que no entiendo, la select se ejecuta correctamente, porque guarda los datos, pero no lo entiendo. Gracias por la ayuda.

PD: Cuando voy a ver almacenamiento en el navegador, la sesion esta creada, se llama sesion, pero no tiene datos.

El archivo de inicio de la sesion.

```
 <?php
/* Funcion para llamar crea la sesion y llamarla */
function inicioSesion() {
    session_name("SESSION");
    session_cache_limiter("nocache");
    session_start();
}

?>
```

El archivo a la conexion a la db, funciona porque los demas .php funcionan

```
<?php
define("IP","127.0.0.1");
define("USUARIO","octubre");
define("CLAVE","octubre");
define("BD","octubres");
?>
```

Comment: ¿Ya ejecutaste la instrucción session_start();?¿Porqué "$canal=@mysqli_connect(IP,USUARIO,CLAVE,BD);$canal=@mysqli_connect(IP,USUARIO,CLAVE,BD);" tiene una @ en la instrucción mysqli_connect?

Comment: Necesitamos ver los archivos `sesionesbd.php` e `inicioSesion.php` para saber cómo se inicia la sesión y cuál puede ser el problema. De lo contrario, estaremos basándonos más en suposiciones. Ten en cuenta que para sesiones basadas en cookies, `session_start()` debe llamarse antes de imprimir cualquier salida... por lo que si en tu código ocurre algún error (que escriben cosas con `echo`), la sesión puede no iniciarse correctamente.

Comment: Es verdad, perdon, no me di cuenta. He actualizado la pergunta con el archivo. Si, la funcion sesion_start( ) la llamo desde inicioSesion() antes de empezar a guardar los datos, por eso, aparece el nombre y el perfil, pero no me explico lo del navegador... y que se guarden unos datos y otros no si la query se ejecuta.

Comment: Como sugerencia mientras desarrollas quítale la @ a tus consultas para realmente sepas que tu código trabaja bien, de lo contrario puede que estés ocultando más posibles errores y no sepas de dónde vienen/ donde salieron.